# power automate : move name of flow to chat section items?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

We created a power automate flow (using "for a selected message"), any message posted to the channel, we click "three dots" and click "more actions" then "See more" to select name of the power automate flow and execute accordingly. This doesnt sound to be user friendly.

Is there any way we can "pin" the name of the flow to somewhere nearest for example under chat section on the bottom of the screen ? So that it becomes more user friendly.

Comment: In chat section, you can pin the Messaging Extensions but not the app.
Also could you please share the repro step or docs which you are following so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft :  This is not repro ...its how to, more information added to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/re-order-the-name-from-quot-more-actions-quot/m-p/2819003#M101126

Comment: @harekrshn, the functionality you are trying to implement doesn't seem to be feasible at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more visibility, posting the answer from comment section:

The functionality you are trying to implement doesn't seem to be feasible at the moment.